# Get the count of numbers doubling using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, logarithm

I am trying to get a count on the number of times a number (`start_value`) doubles until it reaches a particular value (`end_value`) in the cleanest way possible. Consider the following example:

```
id   start_value    end_value

1     40              130
2     100             777
3     0.20            2.1


example 1: 40 * 2 = 80
           80 * 2 = 160
           160 = above value so therefore we had 2 doubles

example 2: 100 * 2 = 200
           200 * 2 = 400
           400 * 2 = 800
           800 = above value so we had 3 doubles

example 3: 0.20 * 2 = 0.4
           0.4 * 2  = 0.8
           0.8 * 2 = 1.6
           1.6 * 2 = 3.2
           3.2 = 4 doubles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want logarithms for this.  Specifically, the exact number of times is the log-of-base-2 of the ratio of the two values.  You want the next higher integer, so you want to round this up.

In Postgres:

```
ceiling(log(2, end_value / start_value))
```

Comment: Your math is right, but the Postgres implementation is wrong. The Postgres `log()` function doesn't work like this. If you don't know Postgres specific details (obviously) it would be prudent to at least test before you post.

Comment: any ideas on how to handle negative numbers using log?

Comment: @godzilla . . .  You should probably just take the absolute value (`abs()`).

Comment: that won't work, for example if i have -3000 as a start value and 2000 as an end value i will get a negative which is not correct, is there a cleaner way of handling this?

Comment: @godzilla . . . What do you want it to return in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Divide the end value by the start value to get the factor between them. For example 130/40 = 3.25. Doubling the value once gives a factor 2, and doubling it twice gives a factor 4, and so on.

You can use the logarithm for base 2 to calculate how many times you need to double the value to get a specific factor. log2(3.25) = 1.7004397... Then you round that up to get the whole number of times that you need to double it.

The binary logarithm can be calculated as log(n) / log(2):

```
select
  id,
  ceil(log(end_value / start_value) / log(2)) as times
from
  TheTable
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/90099/4

Comment: any ideas on how to handle negative numbers using log?

Comment: @godzilla: If you have a negative number, you can't double it to get it higher than a positive number, it just get lower.

Comment: any clean solution to this problem? With edge cases i get problems because of this

Comment: @godzilla: Then you need to decide what result you want in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try below SQL :

```
select id, start_value, end_value, floor(log(end_value / start_value,2)/2)
from TempTable
```

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: Does not work. I provided an answer to explain. Also, `floor()` is the wrong choice here,

Answer (score 0):

Postgres provides two variants of `log()`: [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE)

```
log(dp or numeric)
log(b numeric, x numeric)
```

The variant with two parameters calculates a `logarithm to base b`. Note that:

- It requires [**`numeric`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) input for both parameters
- The 1st parameter is the base.

A correct expression would be:

```
ceil(log(2.0, end_value::numeric / start_value::numeric)) AS times
```

- The explicit cat to `numeric` is only necessary if your columns are of a different data type.
- Input the base as `2.0` instead of `2` to make it `numeric` instead of `integer`

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/35f39/3)